# angularjs setting different options on multiple dropdowns

Tags: html, angularjs, dropdownbox

I hope there's a way to achieve this.
I am creating dropdowns using ng-repeat; the number of dropdowns created depends on the data I retrieve from the database.
Depending on the data,I'd like to set an initial option value for each dropdown.
Consider the following code:

```
 <span class="finds" ng-model="cond" ng-repeat="condin list">
<select ng-model="selected_item" ng-options="condition.name for condition in conditionTypes"></select>

<input ng-model="cond.name"/>
</span>
```

I can change the values of the dropdown by changing the selected_item value but this changes the value of all dropdowns (because the variable is binded).
So is it possible for me to change the value of each dropdown independently without affecting other dropdowns(without creating multiple variables as well)?

Thank you

Comment: no, each select should be bind to separate model

Answer (score 0):

If you want your right drop-down to be filled with appropriate data according to the value in your first select box you should be doing something like this.

Suppose you have two drop-down list like;

```
<select ng-model="first" class="form-control" ng-change="secondcall()">
      <option ng-repeat = "firstdata in firstdatas" value="{{firstdata}}">{{firstdata}}</option>
 </select>
<select ng-model="second" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat = "seconddata in seconddatas" value="{{seconddata}}">{{seconddata}}</option>
</select>
```

In your controller;

```
$scope.secondcall = function () {
  var value = $scope.first;
  //Make an API call to fetch details with the select value and in the success do this

    $scope.seconddatas = data from the api;

};
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to set the value of each dropdown independently.
your suggestion seems approapriate but can you tell me how I can use it.
How can I set the approapriate value for each dropdown using the controller and the $index?

Comment: Yes you need to have separate ng-model for each dropdown

Comment: I don't think its possible dynamically. You need to know how many drop downs will be there and do it according to that.

Comment: yeah that's a bit hard, I mean even if I know how many dropdowns will be there, how can I set ng-models dynamically?
is it possible to set the option value of the dropdown without using ng-model?

Comment: I have tried selected_item_$index but it doesn't work.

let's say that I have and ng-repeat create a pair of 3 dropdowns
drpdwn1  drpdwn1.0
drpdwn3  drpdwn2.0
drpdwn3  drpdwn3.0

for example, if in drpdwn1 I chose age, i want drpdwn1.0 to show a list of ages
if in drpdwn2 i choose marital status,i want a list of status to load on drpdwn2.0 and so on

Comment: I'm currently using this code

<span class="finds" ng-init="setDropdowns()" ng-model="dropdown" ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdowns">

 <select ng-init="setList(dropdown.id)" ng-change="setList(dropdown.id)" ng-model="dropdown.id" ng-options="condition.name as condition.name for condition in conditionTypes"></select>

 {{select_finds.name}}
 <select  ng-model="item.LoadList" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in listData[counter]"></select><br>
 </span>

Comment: The first select creates the left dropdowns with options such as age,status etc.
The second select creates the right dropdowns with the appropriate list.

listData is basically an array containing different lists in it that I want to load depending on the option chosen from the left dropdown.

I can't do this because of binding because if I change the listData index, it changes for all other dropdowns as well.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you want to load second dropdown according to the select value from the first, then why you are putting the dropdowns inside ng-repeat?

Comment: There's only one ng-repeat and that is used to create a set of dropdowns.
I need to retrieve the data from the database and depending on the data I can then define how many dropdowns I will need.
the ng-repeat does that. if, after processing the data I need 2 dropdowns then I'll create two pairs inside the loop
dropdown1  dropdwon1.0  {1.0 should load list depending on the option chosen in 1

dropdown2  dropdown2.0  {2.0 should load list depending on the option chosen in 2

Answer (score 0):

There's only one ng-repeat and that is used to create a set of dropdowns.
I need to retrieve the data from the database and depending on the data I can then define how many dropdowns I will need.
the ng-repeat does that. if, after processing the data I need 2 dropdowns then I'll create two pairs inside the loop
dropdown1  dropdwon1.0  {1.0 should load list depending on the option chosen in 1

dropdown2  dropdown2.0  {2.0 should load list depending on the option chosen in 2